# List editMode behavior broken on iPadOS 16 only

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am wondering if anyone else is seeing this behavior. I have an app that builds for iPadOS 14-16 only where editMode behavior is broken in iOS 16 only. We have a custom edit button design so using the default one(which seems to be the only way to get the drag and drop icon to show) is not an option. Only after dragging a cell or when there are a lot of cells and you scroll off screen does the drag and drop icon show. Using the following code:

```swift
struct Number: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let number: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var testData = Array(1..<10).map { Number(id: UUID().uuidString, number: $0) }
    @State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
    @State var isEditing: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(testData) {
                    TestCellView(title: "\($0.number)")
                }
                .onMove(perform: editMode == .active ? moveRow : nil)
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .padding()
            .navigationBarTitle("Hello")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(editMode == .active ? "Done" : "Edit", action: {
                editMode = editMode == .active ? .inactive : .active
            }))
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        }
    }
    
    private func moveRow(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        withAnimation {
            testData.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
        }
    }
}
```

I have been beating my head against the wall with no results so far.

[image: editMode is on but there is no drag and drop indicator on the right of the cells]

Comment: Just for my understanding of your question,
 is your issue that you do not see the `Edit/Done` button when using the code you show, 
 or only when you use your custom edit button?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added an image. The drag and drop indicator that should show on the right is not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the design of our app the above solutions didn't work for us as iPadOS allows editing of a list even when `editMode` is not `.active`. So we ended up going with a hack/workaround where we show one list that edits/one list that is read-only and switch back and forth.

Something like the code below:

```swift
List {
    if editMode == .active {
        ForEach(testData) {
            TestCellView(title: "\($0.number)")
        }
        .onMove(perform: moveRow)
    } else {
        ForEach(testData) {
            TestCellView(title: "\($0.number)")
        }
    }
}
.environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
.padding()
.navigationBarTitle("Hello")
.navigationBarItems(leading: Button(editMode == .active ? "Done" : "Edit", action: {
    editMode = editMode == .active ? .inactive : .active
}))
.animation(nil, value: editMode.isEditing)
```

It isn't the best solution but it gets the job done.

Comment: This broke again in iPadOS 16.4 and instead of the if statement for editMode being inside the List, moving it outside the list made the icons show up properly again...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your own button, how about using the `.buttonStyle` modifier, and customising the standard `EditButton`, e.g.

```
struct EditButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
        
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        switch editMode?.wrappedValue {
        case .active:
            Image(systemName: "checkmark.square")
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        default:
            Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        }
    }
}

extension ButtonStyle where Self == EditButtonStyle {
    static var edit: Self {
        EditButtonStyle()
    }
}
```

This simplifies your `List`…

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var testData = Array(1..<10).map { Number(id: UUID().uuidString, number: $0) }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(testData) {
                    Text("\($0.number)")
                }
                .onMove(perform: moveRow)
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .padding()
            .navigationBarTitle("Hello")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton().buttonStyle(.edit))
        }
    }
    
    private func moveRow(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        testData.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}
```

[image]